# Starting an IntentService on Activity onStop

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a countdown timer, and I want to make it **still counting even if the app is on background or closed.**

I tried to do it by using IntentService, and calling this method **onStop** of my Activity:

```
private void startTimerService(TimerFragment timer){
    MyTimer myTimer = timer.getMyTimer();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntentService.class);

    intent.putExtra("timer_running", myTimer.isRunning());
    intent.putExtra("pause", myTimer.isPause());

    intent.putExtra("init_time", myTimer.getInitTime());
    intent.putExtra("millis_left", myTimer.getTimeWhenStopped());
    intent.putExtra("end_time", myTimer.getEndTime());

    startService(intent);
}
```

This is my Service class (still in development...):

```
public class TimerIntentService extends IntentService {

private MyTimer myTimer;
private CountDownTimer countdownTimer;

public TimerIntentService() {
    super("TimerIntentService");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras !=  null){
        myTimer = new MyTimer();

        myTimer.setIdExecution(extras.getLong("id_execution"));
        myTimer.setIdExercise(extras.getLong("id_exercise"));
        myTimer.setPosition(extras.getInt("position"));

        myTimer.setRunning(extras.getBoolean("timer_running"));
        myTimer.setPause(extras.getBoolean("pause"));

        myTimer.setInitTime(extras.getLong("init_time"));
        myTimer.setTimeWhenStopped(extras.getLong("millis_left"));
        myTimer.setEndTime(extras.getLong("end_time"));

        if(myTimer.isRunning()){
            createTimer(myTimer.getTimeWhenStopped());
            if(!myTimer.isPause()){
                myTimer.startTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void createTimer(long t){
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(t, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            myTimer.setElapsedTime(l/1000);

            long hour = myTimer.getElapsedTime()/3600;
            long minute = myTimer.getElapsedTime()/60;
            long second = myTimer.getElapsedTime()%60;

            String s = String.format("%02d", hour) + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", minute) +":"
                    + String.format("%02d", second);

            Log.v("Timer Service: ", s);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            cancel();
            myTimer.setRunning(false);

        }
    };

    myTimer.setTimer(timer);
}
}
```

The objective is to when the application is closed or minimized, the IntentService starts the countdown from where it stopped in the Activity, and when the app is open again, the service stops and the app timer starts from where the service countdown stopped.

**Question:** For now, the service is not even starting when I call it onStop.
Is this the right way to use the service? 
Is it right to start it when Activity stops, and stop it when Activity starts? Or should I keep it running the whole time?

Comment: Can you give more information? What do you want to have happen when the timer reaches zero? Do you want that to happen even if the activity is not being shown?

Comment: When Activity is closed and service starts, service will create a Notification updating timer. When it reaches 0, creates a Notification alarm that opens the Activity when clicked. 
But this is further development, for now i just want to make the service to make timer counts, as asked above.

Comment: Sorry if I was not more clear. Can you explain why you are trying to do this? There may be a better way that does not use the solution you are attempting.